# How to represent Collection PLUS Integer in a Stack?

Tags: winforms, design-patterns

We are using a [Stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8hws30f.aspx) to provide the user with a simple "back one" button. We push collections onto the stack and pop them off again when he hits back one.

Today we want to extend this a little bit. When we push a collection onto the stack we want to store an integer alongside the collection. Then when we peek at the stack we want to retrieve the collection PLUS its integer.

What's the best way to push our collection PLUS THE INTEGER onto the stack?

Should we define a Struct or Class for collection plus integer? Or some other way?

Comment: Yes, define a struct or class for this.

Comment: Any collection, or some specialized collection?

Comment: @SWeko it's a list of customers which inherits Component and implements a bunch of interfces, e.g. IBindingListView etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don' t need to create a new class for this purpose. You can simply add your values into the stack like this;

```
stack.Push(new KeyValuePair<int, Collection>(yourInteger, yourCollection));
```

and get them like this;

```
KeyValuePair<int, Collection> valueYouWant = stack.Pop();

valueYouWant.Key   --> Your integer
valueYouWant.Value --> Your collection
```

Comment: doesnt this require the integer to be unique? they wouldn't be in our case

Comment: Nope. The integer may not be unique at all. Note that the `Stack` is not a `Dictionary`. You can push things like;   `stack.Push(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(theInteger1, theCollection1));   stack.Push(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(theInteger1, theCollection1));`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and out-of-the-box solution would be to extend your current container with the integer:

```
public class StackElement : CustomerCollection
{ 
   public int Version {get; set;}
}
```

or make a composition with an integer:

```
public class StackElement
{ 
   public CustomerCollection Customers {get; set;}
   public int Version {get; set;}
}
```

and then use it just as you would use any other thing with a stack:

```
Stack<StackElement> stack = new Stack<StackElement>();
stack.Push(...)
var stackElement = stack.Pop();
```